# How to import library with special characters and numbers using pythonet?

Tags: python, .net, dll

I am trying to call .net DLL from python code using pythonet.

My DLL name is mydll.14.dll

I can add the reference. But not able to import it.

How can i import it? This is my code :

```
  import clr
  import sys

  sys.path.append(r"C:\Folder\Subfolder") 
  clr.AddReference ("mydll.14")
  from mydll.14 import className
```

It's showing syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
from mydll.14 import className
```

is telling Python to find subpackage `14` of package `mydll` and import `classname`.  However `14` is not a valid Python [identifier](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), so Python raises a SyntaxError.

If `14` is really a subpackage of `mydll` then it needs to have a valid name.  If `.14` is a reference to a version then you probably<sup>*</sup> need to give the dll a conformant name such as `mydll_14`.

---

<sup>*</sup>I don't program on Windows, so there may be other solutions.